# Office Word JS API - How to get all comments of a document - Word Desktop Version

Tags: office-js

I'm trying to get all comments of a Word document using the preview (also tried the release) version of the Office JS API, but the error I get is always "NotImplemented" when using in the desktop version of Word, but not online.

Does anyone know when it's going to be release or ever will?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting this issue. Regarding the APIs related to comments, they will be included in the upcoming release. And stay tuned!